# Counting in steps in go

Tags: go

i am trying to solve the following problem but have no nice solution for this.

i have the following float64 0.123456789
and want to count up in the following step-size: 0.0001

so the result should be 0.123400000

my current solution is really ugly and don't works well:

```
var waletMoney float64
var stepSize float64
var tmpMoney float64

waletMoney = 0.123456789
stepSize = 0.0001

tmpMoney = 0.0000000
loop := true
for loop {
    tmpMoney = tmpMoney + stepSize
    // fmt.Println(tmpMoney)
    if tmpMoney+stepSize >= waletMoney {
        loop = false
    }
}
fmt.Println(tmpMoney)
// result is 0.12340000000000251 but should be 0.123400000 or 0.1234
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vM-3qZ05QOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var waletMoney float64
    var stepSize float64
    var tmpMoney float64

    waletMoney = 0.123456789
    stepSize = 0.00001

    tmpMoney = float64(int(waletMoney /stepSize)) *stepSize 

    fmt.Println(tmpMoney)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `float64` uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation which can't exactly represent `0.0001`. Repeatedly adding it is not the same as doing so using decimal (paper & pencil) arithmetic.

One thing you can do to at least avoid multiple rounding errors, is to use a counter and multiply rather than repeated addition which will accumulate rounding errors.

```
tmpMoney = 0.0
loop := true
count := 0
for loop {
    tmpMoney = stepSize * float64(count)
    // fmt.Println(tmpMoney)
    if tmpMoney + stepSize >= waletMoney {
        loop = false
    }
    count += 1
}
```